# Is it possible to create instance of a class based on the typed method when call the method?

Tags: c#, oop

I am not sure is it possible but I would like to create something like this:

```
public static T GetExceptions<T>(string id, string message)
{
    var ex = new T //<== Is this possible? Or in another way?
    {
       Id = id,
       StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
       Message = message
       Type = "Type A"
    };
            
    return ex;
}
```

The ultimate goal is actually want to create a general method and returns custom exception class based on the different exception type input when calling this method.

The main purpose I want to create a general method like this is because every of my exception class is having similar properties like Id, StatusCode, and Message, the only difference is the Type.

So instead of copied the long code all over whenever I have to throw an exception. I was hoping that a general method can return me the exception, then all I have to do is throw it in the Main method.

Comment: How about using [Constraints on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) like e.g. `where T : MyClass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just need a [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to your *base class exception* or *interface* with `new()`

> Constraints specify the capabilities and expectations of a type
> parameter. Declaring those constraints means you can use the
> operations and method calls of the constraining type. If your generic
> class or method uses any operation on the generic members beyond
> simple assignment or calling any methods not supported by
> System.Object, you'll have to apply constraints to the type parameter

In your case you will need a *base class* or *interface* to share a *common contract* between your custom exceptions. When you apply that as a *constraint* it allow to access the common contract in the *generic method*.

Note you will also need the `new` constraint which will allow you to instantiate the class

The only caveat is the [new constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) needs a *parameterless constructor*

> The new constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class
> declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
> new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

In which case, you will need to use [`CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1) (as in [Haydens](http://Hayden) example) and pass in (or set) the parameters

**Given**

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   string Id { get; set; }
   string Message { get; set; }
   HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
   //...
}

public class MyFunkyException : Exception, IMyInterface
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Example**

```
public static T GetExceptions<T>(string id, string message) where T : IMyInterface, new()
{
   var ex = new T
   {
      Id = id,
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
      Message = message,
      //...
   };
      
   return ex;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is cleaner and better than my solution.

Comment: @Hayden note that if the OP doesn't have a default constructor, they will have to use `CreateInstance`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by having a common interface, then use reflection to create the value

**Given**

```
public interface IException
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}

public class TypeAException : IException
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class TypeBException : IException
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Your method can transform into something like this:

```
public static T GetExceptions<T>(string id, string message) where T : class, IException
{
    
    var ex = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as T;
    
    ex.Id = id;
    ex.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    ex.Message = message;
    ex.Type = typeof(T).ToString();
            
    return ex;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = GetExceptions<TypeBException>("id", "message");

Console.WriteLine(result.Type);
```

**Output**

```
Test.TypeBException
```

Comment: Added a reference to your example